# Can I disable or remove a version that was pushed to a reload stream?

Tags: trigger.io

Because of previously reported error I now need to disable the latest pushed version...

Answer (score 0):

For context, this relates to a problem with v1.4.32 of the Trigger.io platform that affected Reload on iOS devices.

---

Yes, you have a couple of options.

The first is to push a Reload update identical to the version you released to the app stores: app installs which are already mid-Reload will continue with that, but any fresh installs or existing installs which haven't started downloading your update will see the latest "no-op" and not do anything.

The second option is going to take more co-ordination between you and us - if we know the exact builds you pushed up to the app store, we can remove our records of the Reload(s) you pushed. As in the first option, currently in-progress Reloads will continue.

Updating the app, building on top of v1.4.33 will update all of your users, no matter what state Reload is in.

If you need help with either of those options, get in touch at support@trigger.io!